# Typescript: check for intersections between union types, ensure all members are unique

Tags: typescript, types, union-types

I have several types which are effectively enums that are referencing different kinds of things, and I also have lookup tables that are agnostic of which type the string is part of. The problem is that this will break if there is any overlap between these types. Here is an example:

```
type SandwichKind = "ham" | "eggSalad" | "meatball"
type SoupKind = "mushroom" | "broccoli" | "potato"

class MenuItem{}
class Soup extends MenuItem {
   soupKind : SoupKind 
   constructor(kind: SoupKind){
       super()
       this.soupKind = kind
   }
}
let caloriesByMenuItem : Record<SandwichKind | SoupKind, number> = {
    ham : 100,
    eggSalad: 150,
    meatball: 400,
    mushroom: 100,
    broccoli: 125,
    potato: 75
}
```

The example above works fine as it is. But perhaps my incredibly creative chef decides to add meatball Soup to the menu. And we call the `SoupKind` `"meatball"`. Now I go around updating lookup tables and adding entries and eventually get to `caloriesByMenuItem` where an entry for `"meatball"` already exists. Since I've obviously already filled this in, I skip it. Now the Kind for meatball soup and meatball sandwiches are stuck being the same and therefore stuck with the same calorie count.

What I need to do is ensure that `soupKind` and `sandwhichKind` have no overlap and ensure that the code does not build if there is overlap.

Comment: The code here isn't a [mre]; could you [edit] it so it is? For example, `Record<SandwichKind | SoupKind>` doesn't compile properly.  Please consider copying your code and pasting it into a standalone IDE like The TypeScript Playground, and resolving any issues you find (unless they're the issue you're trying to solve).

Comment: @jcalz Thanks, forgot to add the second parameter to the Record<> thing and was being lazy about not checking the code compiled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing built in to TypeScript but there are a number of ways to implement something like this yourself.  The overlap between two [unions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of string [literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) consists exactly of their [intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types):

```
type Overlap = SandwichKind & SoupKind;    
//   ^? type Overlap = "meatball"
```

If you want to ensure that there is no overlap, you need to make sure that the intersection is [the `never` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#the-never-type), preferably generating an error otherwise.  Since only `never` is assignable to `never`, you just need to try to assign the overlap type to `never` somewhere.

This could be done purely at the type level (so there's no emitted JavaScript) like this:

```
type ErrorIfOverlapping<T extends never = Overlap> = void;
```

We don't care what `ErrorIfOverlapping<T>` evaluates to (it's just `void`). All we care about is that the generic type parameter `T` is [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) to `never`, and that it [defaults](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-3.html#generic-parameter-defaults) to `Overlap`.  Defaults always need to be assignable to constraints.  If `Overlap` has members, then the `= Overlap` part above will cause a compiler error, otherwise it will be fine:

```
type ErrorIfOverlapping<T extends never = Overlap> = void; // error!
//                                   ---> ^^^^^^^
// If there's an error here, it's because there's an overlap between
// SandwichKind and SoupKind; check the type below 
type Overlap = SandwichKind & SoupKind;
//   ^? type Overlap = "meatball"

type ErrorIfOverlapping<T extends never = Overlap> = void; // no error
//                                   ---> ^^^^^^^
// If there's an error here, it's because there's an overlap between
// SandwichKind and SoupKind; check the type below 
type Overlap = SandwichKind & SoupKind;
//   ^? type Overlap = never
```

So that's one of many approaches to making sure two unions of string literal types don't overlap.

---

But what if you have a larger number of unions of string literal types and want to make sure that *no pair of them* overlap?  That's outside of the scope of the question as asked, but it's possible someone might come here caring about that?  You could, of course, manually generate the pairs.  But we can make TypeScript compute them.

Here's a `Pairs<T>` utility type to turn a [tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types) into a union of pairs of tuple elements:

```
type Pairs<T extends any[], A extends [any, any] = never> =
    T extends [infer F, ...infer R] ?
    Pairs<R, A | { [I in keyof R]: [F, R[I]] }[number]> : A;

type Test = Pairs<[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]>;
// type Test = [1, 2] | [1, 3] | [1, 4] | [1, 5] | [2, 3] |
//  [2, 4] | [2, 5] | [4, 5] | [3, 4] | [3, 5];
```

That's a [tail-recursive conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-5.html#tail-recursion-elimination-on-conditional-types) that uses [variadic tuple types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-0.html#variadic-tuple-types) to check if the input tuple has any elements.  If so, it shifts the first one off into `F`, and keeps the rest as a tuple `R`, and then generats the pairs of `[F, R[I]]` for each numeric index `I` in `R`.  Then it recurses, accumulating the results on to `A`.  Otherwise it just returns the accumulated results in `A`.

Once you have that, you can write `Pairs<[SandwichKind, SoupKind, OtherKind, ⋯]>` to avoid manually determining each pair.  Then you distribute your overlap-checking function over the result, possibly making sure to encode enough information so that the output, if not `never`, tells you which pairs of inputs are the problem.  Possibly like this:

```
type Overlap<T extends [any, any]> =
    T extends [infer L, infer R] ? L & R extends never ? never : [L, R, L & R] : never;
```

That's a [distributive conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types) it will automatically turn unions into unions.  If the left `L` and right `R` elements of the input pair have an overlap, we output `[L, R, L & R]`, which hopefully provides enough information.

We can put it all together like:

```
type SandwichKind = "ham" | "eggSalad" // | "meatball"
type SoupKind = "mushroom" | "broccoli" | "potato" | "meatball";
type ActingKind = "earnest" | "maudlin" // | "ham";
type ListOfKinds = [SandwichKind, SoupKind, ActingKind];

type ErrorIfOverlapping<T extends never = OverlapList> = void; // okay
// if there's an error here ----------->  ^^^^^^^^^^^ 
// then there's a problem here:
type OverlapList = Overlap<Pairs<ListOfKinds>>
//   ^? type OverlapList = never
```

or

```
type SandwichKind = "ham" | "eggSalad" | "meatball"
type SoupKind = "mushroom" | "broccoli" | "potato" | "meatball";
type ActingKind = "earnest" | "maudlin" // | "ham";

type ErrorIfOverlapping<T extends never = OverlapList> = void; // error!
// if there's an error here ----------->  ^^^^^^^^^^^ 
// then there's a problem here:
type OverlapList = Overlap<Pairs<ListOfKinds>>
//   ^? type OverlapList = [SandwichKind, SoupKind, "meatball"]
```

Note that in the latter case it evaluates to `[SandwichKind, SoupKind, "meatball"]` which should hopefully be enough to tell you "uh oh, `SandwichKind` and `SoupKind` both contain `"meatball"`; I should fix it".

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEBxA9mgJkg3gKDySKQBcBPGZAZRGEwHcBLeACwGlG6kBeJAIhbg+SAD78IAcwk0ANiEzCA9ItH9IIEgCMQMmX0LFylJFTQBXGBy68+YM1BYAnDGGFi+m5-HhoZjN-wwaCQaaAG2EBraunwA3AZERsgAgvAknBJW2DaRjsDQJOFgIGaYfsBKKu6CrvEJSKCQsAjIACr0aACqwIxowFC49cSkFMgAoo7OjgCSAGYA8gBuEI5yMDAZADytSBAAHiQQdAP5y448SEsrawB8F4tojJjxw8PKrx+fX98AtH93AD0gcCAUNiO85qQWCsIAByAa0XaTNDnaGOCAAGiQjBI8KQmgg8BKUGQJDRcIRwCQaDOa3xEBI9AgRzBRHeNDoTFYWSQtGwpgsWViSFYhIA1lDSaN6TI0PQkKyRsYrqsQDALhyGMx2JxsAAyEzmSy6l6fd5EAEAfgIwwAvjbDNKADKMKAkeazLIDXgAbU1XJ1dCxAuNQaQqXSwEyuoAunVhkkkAAFECMRxQba7A5HTCUsg+mNY5JZw7HJA+2hkLGVmMXU4rO7cRU7fal3PlzizFZIABiWIAdIPO92AEq1y3J1PpzYjouqHDl6bYqliiBkNCzJBjgBc5b7W590xjtdtPuAZjABMcMbuu+S8cdytpaszrZzAwrwCrvK-N4uLezMsfWHc4nSxECt3HJAnSQA0RxLd8GggM4kAnetzl3H0wK3LEYLg2td3Qh9EmlCYpjmFU1g2KNX0A9t0IuSi1RdN1GyQB4nmFd40DFEAyHqd5GE3MkYTxREVimJBySQP5ZLk-4LRBJSAQVN4VBEqkRPRMSkBgZxNBkCAwCkmFt3qRMmJgFiSEY58YE2FM0wzayPS9G4bgElQLQnCy7OsutkJWAg8HtPBGmgOBECQAAheRBnM6V-W1HkbBqcJJGkHR5CKSItB0PQEuMEMUrUewnBccJPDQbxfH8VQ+CCEISDCer1DymJTRI4wIwyEq+FyfI3SKEoyk4Sp6rS4iGnACKWiQdouh6PoBnwRVEzIlEKLs6iJFotsTkC85eEstiOOeRVzW+K7ruIWTAWUi6VEhLSKR-JFJPJcDcQGAkiXsUlyTEqkaWuNV6UZZlgEekw+QDHk+UNQUTRFaF4AlESlWQAlZXlNbpUsjVYeS3VYMR0Nzq+S6rQdIhQoTZ1XXdT1dW9csku5XVgyNLIizSXrYymxNHOnAD9p-fNC3DBCgMratfwCs5G2baX22A4Au3OfdB37CCx1QxVhYzWcpbEBdD2XJBV3XTcdz3LER0PY8kFPc9LxWP870F-G7L2xDP2-Gsla+UW-Yg7DdagvCtxVg6ULQw6kEw7DjajvXCMOr3jA2mYFm2rYQ7LBjjr8xnTseZ4kHeCSUQAQk87FhMByl3pREz0Rk+T5LuJBlKU1TwXU6FNKb3ldP0wzjPJMz6afUGrMZ2y54cqdnMZ1yWfc+vvMxy4S7dC4-SJjmw2Kzm1Fy6I9BjAhQqFlffbLSsCznN8Za-OWyFrXh0KD4gC9ViCWshzq1HOOeohsZxzlNouC2VsNyQUwvuB2R4TxngvFeD24Y6iJlaAUC4ECfQAEYsQACYsQAGYsQABYsQAFYbzxHeDgvBvpiFIBIbWMQRCKGcPLGwqhvDuFIHoaoH0ZCkDkM4Xgc0YjqGCPESIrhNDhGCMoUgARoi1H0NiEAA)

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I was writing this question when I had an idea on how to solve it and the idea worked, so I'm just gonna post it anyway in case someone else out there needs this.

The solution for me was to declare some useless variables (I'd advise you also include a comment such as mine so that future you, in rush to deploy something, doesn't forget why you did this):

```
type SandwichKind = "ham" | "eggSalad" | "meatball"
type SoupKind = "mushroom" | "broccoli" | "potato" | "meatball"


/*
 * These dictionaries must be empty. They ensure that we have not added the same
 * string into two type definitions. 
 * If Typescript is mad about this, it means you broke something.
 * Go rename whatever you just created so it doesn't conflict.
 */
const checkTypesAreUnique1 : Record<SandwichKind & SoupKind , string> = {};
```

Running this code will give you the error:

```
error TS2739: Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'Record<"meatball", string>': meatball
```

Now that you have been notified of the problem, you can rename the `"meatball"` Soup to `"meatballSoup"` and the error will go away.

The only downside of this solution is that if you have lots of types (e.g. `SoupKind`, `SandwichKind`, `SaladKind`, `BurgerKind`...), you need to do this for every combination. So for 10 types you would need  45 lines of code. But at that point you should really really change your strategy altogether.

If there is a built-in way to do this in TS, please let me know. I wasn't able to find it.

Comment: There's no "built in" way to do this that I know of, and there are lots of possible ways to write this and I'm not sure by what metric you'd rate the different approaches in order to determine which one is "the" answer to the question.  Is the "10 kinds" an issue you want to explore in this question? If so you might want to edit the other post to say that you need it to scale linearly in number of kinds.  Then I could maybe suggest something like the code in [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/wj8Ekm). How do you want to proceed here?

Comment: @jcalz What I think of as "the" answer to the question is kind of irrelevant in my opinion. My answer is perfect for my situation, but the purpose of SO is to provide generic solutions and re-usable answers. If you have a solution that can solve a wider range of problems than mine, I'm sure someone will find value in you posting it.


PS: I would probably advise adding some comments to that playground though, and making sure it compiles. Because tbh I cannot fathom what is going on there, lol

Comment: It compiles if and only if you have not made a mistake. If I do write up an answer I will be sure to explain it fully, but I'm not sure it's worth the effort, since the risk-reward ratio for "someone" finding value in it doesn't look great.  Not sure yet.

Comment: @jcalz I have made sure that there is no overlap in the three kinds, but it still says `Exported type alias 'Overlap' has or is using private name ''` and `':' expected` which seem like syntax errors rather than the kind of error that would come from an overlap. Perhaps I am doing something wrong.

Comment: No, uh, you're right. I see that the link above has an error I didn't notice for some reason , sorry.  [Here is a better one](https://tsplay.dev/Nl8qRN), I hope, anyway.

Comment: @jcalz that is very impressive. While my solution does work perfectly well for my application, I would be very interested in how you accomplished that and would encourage you to write an answer, even if it isn't a super beginner-friendly one.