# How to check if objects have overlapping leaves and produce a helpful error message

Tags: typescript

I have 2 objects that should not have any common leaves:

```ts
const translated = {
  a: {
    b: {
      c: "Hello",
      d: "World"
    }
  }
};

const toTranslate = {
  a: {
    b: {
      d: "Everybody"
    }
  }
};
```

Code above should produce an error: 'a.b.d' is in both objects.

I can easily write a unit test to chek that, but I was trying to produce a nice error message compile-time.

My attempt:

```ts
type Leaves<T> = T extends object ? { [K in keyof T]:
  `${Exclude<K, symbol>}${Leaves<T[K]> extends never ? "" : `.${Leaves<T[K]>}`}`
}[keyof T] : never

type TranslatedLeaves = Leaves<typeof translated>
type ToTranslateLeaves = Leaves<typeof toTranslate>

type Overlap = TranslatedLeaves & ToTranslateLeaves
type ErrorIfOverlapping<T extends never = Overlap> = void;
```

See:

- [Typescript: deep keyof of a nested object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58434389/typescript-deep-keyof-of-a-nested-object)
- [Typescript: check for intersections between union types, ensure all members are unique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76419386/typescript-check-for-intersections-between-union-types-ensure-all-members-are)

Unfortunately, this gives me only: `Type 'string' does not satisfy the constraint 'never'.`

Is it possible to produce an error message with all leaves that are in common?

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBFBOBDSAbRUCmATGBeGA3gFAwyIBchJpMARpcTTcJQEQASGKKIrANNSZY2AdRDwUWVoJgBfavNkBuIkVCRYUEABUkqdBjxVSFYzXpmhbAKIA3DPACetEFkfSm80opWqojgAdDABkMRHsIAB5tAD4jbRgMAA9MMCwIGBBaACsMYFgAfkIYAG0AaRgASzAYAGsMRxAAMxhtAF1yagADABICayTgFABXLAxIsr4YCEcAWxcUGNk%200PCMKO1ytrjk1PSYMAx7eBgi1lYYSi6AOhWwiOitpa7ZLqJZEvrGlvbLg6OHH5AoZdMgIGhMFhVhEjND1pF-EFmnA9OCDFgYkRESCdKiIRg4Rl8ISEcDkVpQfpMJiscCYAB5Y5oALxPHowkwABkrVxYPxhNpQRg1ng8HEAEkmoyHMyAtUAObRRIpDBpDKHY5GaUSRABOL4WwgSpYXxEIA)

Comment: You really want custom errors as requested in [ms/TS#23689](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/23689); there are various workarounds; something like [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/mbrk8m) shows one possible way forward. Does that fully address the question, or am I missing something?

Comment: @jcalz that fully addresses my question, can you write it down as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript doesn't really have very customizable error messages. There's a longstanding open feature request at [microsoft/TypeScript#23689](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/23689) asking for "invalid" or "throw" types, which are like a flavor of [`never`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#the-never-type) which cause a custom compiler warning when encountered.  Since this feature doesn't exist, there are workarounds.

The easiest workaround is to write a type which contains the message you want to see (usually as some sort of string [literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) or a [template literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html) or even a [tuple](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types) mixing string literals and types), and making it specific enough that in practice only `never` will be assignable to it (you won't accidentally make a compatible type).  Then you could use the type in place of `never`, and you'll see something with more information in it. It still won't be a *pretty* message, and you'd have to deal with `"type 'Foo' is not assignable to type '["Oops, I expected", Bar, "but got", Foo, "instead"]'"` but hopefully it at least gives developers something they could possibly use to proceed.

---

For your example code: we could use the type `` [`"${Overlap}" overlaps`] ``, a one-element tuple type with a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of warning messages.  The only reasonable way that `Overlap` would be assignable to  `` [`"${Overlap}" overlaps`] `` is if `Overlap` is `never` (since it is assignable to anything).  That suggests:

```
type ErrorIfOverlapping<T extends [`"${Overlap}" overlaps`]
  = Overlap> = void;
//  ~~~~~~~
// Type 'string' does not satisfy the 
// constraint '["\"a.b.d\" overlaps"]'
```

The error isn't the best, but it mentions `"a.b.d" overlaps` which should hopefully be enough to help a developer fix the problem.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.3.3#code/MYewdgzgLgBFBOBDSAbRUCmATGBeGA3gFAwyIBchJpMARpcTTcJQEQASGKKIrANNSZY2AdRDwUWVoJgBfavNkBuIkVCRYUEABUkqdBjxVSFYzXpmhbAKIA3DPACetEFkf8ZpDGwAWDjNJM8qSKKkRQjgAOhgAyGIj2EAA82gB8RtowGAAemGBYEDAgtABWGMCwAPyEMADaANIwAJZgMADWGI4gAGYw2gC65NQABgAkBNbZwCgArlgYSfV8MBCOALYuKKmy43EJGMnaDf3pOXkFMGAY9vAw1aysMJTDAHS78Ykpx9vDssNEslqHS6vQGT0u1wcqgi0T6eggaEwWD2iSMKIOSRhGB6cHhiOwqXCUUM2h0eIM6MK+EpmOJOK0umQCIMhKJsN0AEYjFj6eSkSosXCAEzcum9Bl8jBhQUAeRuaEiGUlyI+BxgADI+mSmfjKUQAPT6mgAPUqbMM1ng8HEAElunKHArIi0AOYpLK5DD5Qq1YascYOiSISKyR4geXBiDDfrUfCBhXpfC2EBNLAqQ2kAB+2ZzmYNRu0xJgAHJoPBXcWYFgQGqwCBYBB0E0IN1HHA-DB8zB1GXEC1YMXaqwADqsRAvWgvLCjooRyIQVj9YuqIhAA)